# How to resolve confict on intelliJ?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, pull-request, conflict

I made a pull request on intelliJ and i got some conflicts.

I don't know how to resolve it from intelliJ.

I looked for the 'conflicts' window but without success, it doesn't want to open.
On github in the 'pull request' section, the 'resolve conflict' button is disbale. They show me the differences but they don't allow me to modify or to make a choice between which version I want to keep.

[image]

Comment: Check here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolve-conflicts.html

Answer (score 0):

Resolve conflicts dialog appears after clicking Merge.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resolving-conflicts.html#distributed-version-control-systems

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4415162387090-Where-s-the-git-resolve-conflict-menu/comments/4415148204178